Driven $RLC$ circuit why is the permanent signal sinusoidal and why two degrees of freedom (amplitude and phase)?
In a second-order ODE with constant coefficients, with a sinusoidal RHS term (such as the ODE of the driven $RLC$ circuit), how do we know:

that the particular solution (i.e. the permanent signal) is also sinusoidal, with the same periodicity as the RHS term function?

that this particular solution has exactly two degrees of freedom (i.e. the amplitude and the phase)?




that the particular solution (i.e. the permanent signal) is also sinusoidal, with the same periodicity as the RHS term function?

Answer 1: Because the system is linear.
Answer 2: Can you find another solution that satisfies the ODE? (Realize that ODE's are often solved by "guessing" a solution and then showing that your guess satisfies the equation, rather than by any systematic method)

that this particular solution has exactly two degrees of freedom (i.e. the amplitude and the phase)

Because it's a second order ODE, and so there are 2 boundary conditions required to define a solution.
That said, there are other ways to express these d.o.f. besides amplitude and phase. You could also write the solution as
$$A\cos\omega t + B\sin\omega t$$
with d.o.f. $A$ and $B$.
Or as
$$Ae^{i\omega t}  + A^* e^{-i\omega t}$$
where the coefficients of the two terms must be complex conjugates to produce a real-valued solution, but $A$ is a complex number so the solution still has two d.o.f.
